# How to automaticly reset tmux window indexes

Tags: tmux

Let's say, I have five windows open in tmux session. I close the window at index 1, so I am left with windows on indexes 0, 2, 3 and 4. Is there a way to reinex them automaticly (so that the result would be 0, 1, 2 and 3)? I know i could switch positions of the windows until I get there, is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
       renumber-windows [on | off]
               If on, when a window is closed in a session, automatically renum-
               ber the other windows in numerical order.  This respects the
               base-index option if it has been set.  If off, do not renumber
               the windows.
```

Put it in your tmux conf.

```
set -g renumber-windows on
```